# Не получается запустить docker с базой данных postgresql 16

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

при попытке запустить контейнеры с помощью команды

*docker-compose up --build*

выдаёт ошибку:

> Attaching to db_pg_16-1, site-1 db_pg_16-1  | psql: error: connection
> to server at "db_pg_16" (172.18.0.2), port 5432 failed: Connection
> refused db_pg_16-1  |   Is the server running on that host and
> accepting TCP/IP connections? db_pg_16-1 exited with code 2

До какого-то момента времени (недавно продолжил работу над проектом спустя неделю-2), всё работало замечательно, поэтому могут быть подозрения на кривые обновления 16 версии

попробовал советы из [этого вопроса](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40532399/unable-to-connect-to-server-for-postgres), но поскольку я использую docker, где в контейнере linux-postgres, а так-же к которому я не имею доступ, пока не запущу контейнер - ничего не помогло.

пробовал гуглить:
советовали удалить лишние сети, но это не помогло;
пробовал поменять айпи адрес в ручную (с  172.18.0.2 на 192.168.1.6) - толку 0;
пробовал указать диапазон портов

dockerfile базы данных:

```
FROM postgres:16

ENTRYPOINT ["psql", "-d", "postgresql://sandbox_user:sandbox_password@db_pg_16:5432/sandbox"]
```

compose.yml (вырезал часть с контейнером самого сайта):

```
services:
  db_pg_16:
    build:
      ./db_docker/.
    image: postgres:16
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: sandbox
      POSTGRES_USER: sandbox_user
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: sandbox_password
    ports:
      - 5432
    volumes:
      - ./src/main/resources/schema.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/schema.sql
volumes:
  db:
networks:
  ipv4host:
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
        - subnet: 192.168.1.0/24
```

UPD: Попробовал запустить проект в Windows Sandbox в диапазоне портов 5432:5434 - не помогло, ошибка та же
Так-же попробовал на основной машине запустить с таким-же диапазоном портов - не помогло

Comment: `ENTRYPOINT ["psql"` — вы уничтожили команду запуска сервера, заменив её командой подключения к теперь уже несуществующему серверу. Зачем?

Comment: @andreymal, а какую тогда команду нужно ? Я в докере совсем недавно и не особо понимаю что к чему.

Comment: Никакую. Да и dockerfile в принципе вообще не нужен, и этот `build: ./db_docker/.` можно (или даже нужно) стереть

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Лично у меня получилось запустить контейнер только после обновления версии с     image: **postgres:16** до image: **postgres:16.2-alpine**.

Надеюсь кому-то да поможет